# C double linked list insert based on location

Tags: c, generics, doubly-linked-list

I am working on a generic form of a double linked list, so I have :
list structure :

```
int size;  
struct elem *head;  
struct elem *current;  
struct elem *tail;
```

elem structure :

```
void *data;  
struct elem *next;  
struct elem *prev;
```

I am having a hard time implementing a function allowing me to push a new element before the current one. Here is what I came up with for the moment :

```
t_list *my_list_add_before(t_list *list, void *data)  
{
    struct elem *elem = malloc(sizeof(*elem));
    elem->data = data;
    if(list->size == 0)
    {
        list->head = elem;
        list->current = elem;
        list->tail = elem;
        elem->prev = NULL;
        elem->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
       elem->next = list->current;
       elem->prev = list->current->prev;
       elem->prev->next = elem;
       list->current->prev = elem;
    }
    list->size = list->size + 1;
    return (list);
}
```

But my `list->head->next` seem to point to `NULL`. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify `list->current->prev->next` *before* `list->current->prev`, currently you effectively do `elem->next = elem`.

Comment: I swapped both line as you suggested, but when I try to display my linked list, I can only display one line. (my list-size = 45)

Comment: You are also not treatingk the case where `list->current == list->head` correctly. You need to update `list->head` after inserting before the current head.